# deploy on Heroku a docker image (with volumes), without having source code

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, docker-volume, heroku-cli

I need to deploy on Heroku a Docker image I have from a public registry.
Such image needs some params to be run, including a certificate file.
Locally, I can use `docker compose` specifying in the `docker-compose.yml` file all the *env* vars and *volumes*.

```
# === docker-compose.yml ===
services:
  my_service:
    image: public.images.repo/my-service
    container_name: my_service
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/public.pem:/public.pem
    environment:
      - CERT_PATH=/public.pem
```

Unfortunately, I've just seen that Heroku doesn't support docker compose.

I see that is supports the [heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) file, but it requires to have the `Dockerfile`, that I don't have and can't modify since I only have the image. And, apparently, there is no *volume* field.

```
# === heroku.yml ===
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
    worker: worker/Dockerfile
release:
  image: worker
```

How can I deploy a docker container, with volumes to import certificate files?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku does not support Docker volumes at all](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#unsupported-dockerfile-commands):

> ### Unsupported Dockerfile commands
>
> `VOLUME` - Volume mounting is not supported. The [filesystem of the dyno is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

You could create a custom image based on the public image that gets the certificate file some other way.

Without more information about the container you're trying to run it's hard to say much more.